# Connecting to TFS via IIS User

Tags: asp.net, iis, tfs

I deployed a small Webapplication, which wants to connect to the TFS.
Everything working fine so far except the Error:

```
TF30063: You are not authorized to access https://tfs.argusnet.ch/tfs/defaultcollection.
```

So I checked in the IIS under "IIS Manager Permissions" what User is there and trusted this one in the TFS. This user  is also shown on the IIS Page in brackets after the Server Name.
But this doesn't help.

Sadly I'm not sure if the Problem is at the TFS-Part of the IIS-Part.

Could you give me a Hint, how to make this work?

With best regards

Matthias

Comment: Is your TFS an online hosted one (Cloud..)? The account you used in IIS to run the application pool is a AD account of your domain, right? If it is a TFS online it might be necessary to use specific credentials in your service to connect to the TFS: `TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc= new TfsTeamProjectCollection(tfsUrl, new TfsClientCredentials(credentials));`

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks. I did as you said but used the NetWorkCredential Class, which seems to work now as well.